# Are upgrade ports randomized in different times?

Tags: sid-meiers-pirates

In Sid Meier's Pirates I was looking for a place to upgrade my double hammocks to triple hammocks to increase crew space. When I docked into Port-a-Prince I noticed that the bronze cannon upgrade wasn't there anymore. Are the possibilities of finding triple hammocks rare (because they're a legendary upgrade)? Or do the upgrades just rotate throughout programmed cities so it's hard to find it?

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but I think its randomized per game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the upgrades are randomly distributed. I almost always base myself out of the same ports, and the items available change from game to game (along with how attractive the governors daughters are ;)